# VBA Макрос для переноса строки таблицы по условию

Tags: строки, excel, vba, макрос

Всем доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь написать макрос на VBA для Excel для переноса строки из таблицы на одном листе на другой при вводе в определенный столбец определенных данных. Написал обработчик события:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim table1 As ListObject, table2 As ListObject, table3 As ListObject

    Set table1 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Имя листа").ListObjects("Таблица1")
    Set table2 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Имя листа").ListObjects("Таблица2")
    Set table3 = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Имя листа").ListObjects("Таблица3")
    
    If Target.Count > 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Application.Intersect(Target, table1.ListColumns(2)) Then
        If Target.Value = "Îòâàë" Then
            removeFailed (Target.EntireRow)
        End If
        Exit Sub
    
    ElseIf Application.Intersect(Target, table2.ListColumns(2).Range) Then
        If Target.Value = "Условие" Then
            removeFailed (Target.EntireRow)
        End If
        Exit Sub
    
    ElseIf Application.Intersect(Target, table1.ListColumns(2).Range) Then
        If Target.Value = "Условие" Then
            removeFailed (Target.EntireRow)
        End If
        Exit Sub
    
    Else
        Exit Sub
    
    End If
End Sub
```

и саму функцию, которая осуществляет перенос:

```
Function removeFailed(targetRow As Range)
    Dim l
    
    targetRow.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Имя листа назначения").Select
    l = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Имя листа назначения").ListObjects("Таблица назначения").Range.End(xlDown)
    Rows(l & ":" & l).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Имя листа").Select
    targetRow.Delete
End Function
```

При выполнении вылетает ошибка "Type Missmatch". Подскажите пожалуйста советом, что я сделал неверно и как исправить все так, чтобы скрипт выполнял необходимые действия. Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Где вылетает? На каком операторе?

Comment: на If Application.Intersect(Target, table1.ListColumns(2)) Then, но с этим уже разобрался - теперь вылетает "Object required" при вызове функции removeFailed (((

Comment: CALL добавьте - это всё же функция, а не процедура...

Comment: Функции предназначені для возврата знченя, Вы же функцией пытаетесь производить изменения на листах... Неправильно это. Передавайте управление не функции, а другой процедуре. `Target.EntireRow` - зачем передавть целую строку? Достаточно диапазон с данными. Зачем определять, в какой таблице изменение, если можно обойтись 'Target.Row'? Зачастую (в основом) выделение диапазонов лишнее, копировать/изменять  можно без 'Select'. Для нормального решения нужно видеть примеры

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы. Да, возможно вы правы, просто я не очень в VBA - можно поподробнее с Target.Row, диапазон (там не ячейки, а именно вставленная таблица), call и использование процедуры?

Answer (score 0):

"l=" не нужен. И Call в VBA тоже не обязателен. Скорее всего функция возвращает значение по типу не соответствующее l (variant). просто пишите функцию и аргументы без скобок - этим visual basic до 6 версии и VBA отличает функцию с возвращением значения от просто вызова без возвращаемого. По возможности не объявляйте переменные без типа. Правильно:

```
Dim A as Integer
Dim b as Long
Dim C as TextBox
```